# Disable buffering of repeated button clicks

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, interface

When the user clicks a button, an action is started but if the user quickly clicks the button 10 times, it will execute 10 times.  I guess the disable doesn't take effect until control returns from the event.

```
- (IBAction)btnQuickCheckClick:(id)sender {
  @try {
    self.btnQuickCheck.enabled = NO ;
    // Next line takes about 3 seconds to execute:
    [self pollRouter] ;
  }  
  @finally {
    self.btnQuickCheck.enabled = YES ;
  }    
}
```

Comment: You answered the question yourself.  You're doing the poll synchronously, so the UI never has a chance to update to disable the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the UI by running the run loop after disabling the button before polling:

```
- (IBAction)btnQuickCheckClick:(id)sender {
    self.btnQuickCheck.enabled = NO;
    // give some time for the update to take place
    [self performSelector:@selector(pollRouterMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];   
}
- (void)pollRouterMethod {
    @try {
        [self pollRouter];
    } @catch (NSException * e) { }
    // re-enable the button
    self.btnQuickCheck.enabled = YES;
}
```

Of course, this method is no substitute for running a time intensive task on another thread.  For long tasks, multithreading is almost always the way to go.

Comment: The one hassle with this is that it is basically "daisy-chaining" so if I have an interface to afterwards and I don't want it in the pollRouterMethod I have to do some more tricks.  Trying it out though.

Comment: I rearranged the program structure a little and used this method.  Because I didn't want to adjust the interface in the "pollRouterMethod" (as above), I used 3 methods:
1 buttonClickMethod disables buttons and does the performSelector trick, which points to:
2 updateRouterMethod which directly calls pollRouterMethod and then re-enables the buttons.

Comment: I rearranged the program structure a little and used this method.  Because I didn't want to access the button interface in the "pollRouterMethod" (as above), I used 3 methods:
***1*** buttonClickMethod disables buttons and does the performSelector trick, which points to:
***2*** updateRouterMethod which directly calls ***3*** pollRouterMethod and then control returns to ***2***, which re-enables the buttons.  /// THANKS

Answer (score 1):

another way to do this is with blocks :

Big Pro : you don't need to create an extra method :)

```
- (IBAction)btnQuickCheckClick:(id)sender {
    //UI changes must be done in the main thread
    self.btnQuickCheck.enabled = NO;

    //do your thing in a background thread
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT ,0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^(){
        @try {
            //do your thing here
            [self pollRouter];

        } @catch (NSException * e) {
            //handle the exception, if needed

        } @finally {
            //change to the main thread again and re-enable the UI
            dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
            dispatch_async(mainQueue, ^(){
                self.btnQuickCheck.enabled = YES;
            });
        }
    });
}
```

This will run `pollRouter` in a background thread. So if you are not modifying the UI or other non thread safe things in there you want to use this approach :) Otherwise go for @Alex's approach

Comment: Thanks - great example.  However, in this case the app is a single-purpose router-polling app so I do want to lock it up during the few seconds while the polling is taking place.

Comment: This won't lock up anything. In fact is for not locking up things while doing `pollRouter`. `pollRouter` is done in another thread so even if you are doing intensive or time-taking time stuff it won't affect the user interface.

Comment: Note above, "so I DO want to lock it up", ie "lock up" = good